# Testing for stationary process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, time-series, stationary-processes

I have just started a study in probability and statistics and come across stationary processes.

Rather baffled on how to test a process (Xt)t∈Z is stationary through (Zt)t∈Z to be a sequence of standard normally distributed random variables.

For example:
Xt = exp(Zt−1 − Zt + Zt+1) for all t ∈ Z.

So in order to test for stationarity, the mean would need to a constant? How does one calculate the mean of a time series?

Comment: Are you dealing with _strict_ stationarity or _weak_ stationarity?